# How make snippets like Google Analytics/Facebook Pixel/Anothers scripts?

Tags: javascript, django

I dont know how ask this question. What i want is learn how make snippets scripts to send to my customers.

Example:

On my site, the customers personalize a widget to use in own website (Widget Purchase Counter). Now, I want this customer copy script on my site and paste the script on you website, like Google Analytics/Facbook pixel do.

I Want some like this:

```
<script src="www.mywebsite.com/script.js?UNIQUE_ID_CUSTOMER_EXAMPLE"></script>
```

Google Example:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In this moment i make this solution:

```
    <script
            id="myModalScript"
            data-image="URL_IMAGE.jpg"
            data-code="clienteVIP"
            data-title="Membros Exclusivos possuem até 10% de desconto!"
            data-message="Se inscreva como membro exclusivo e receba o seu desconto agora mesmo!"
            data-button-yes="Sim, quero meu desconto"
            data-button-no="Não, continuar sem desconto"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="www.mymodal.com/script.js?v1.0.2">
    </script>
```

And, inside the script.js, i get the values:

```
//Get values from script
    const omnibeesModalCode = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-code");
    const omnibeeslModalTitle = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-title");
    const omnibeeslModalMessage = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-message");
    const omnibeesModalImagem = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-image");
    const omnibeesModalYes = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-button-yes");
    const omnibeesModalNo = document.getElementById("myModalScript").getAttribute("data-button-no");
```

This script is not safe and not beauty.

Another words: My Script works, but i want optmize!
Like scripts in https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Im coding in Django my website.

Comment: you need to implement an API for this, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Thanks Constantin, im noob in django (and programer), i will take a time to learn about django rest.